# extract graph from roads of city in python and use it in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I wanted to turn the roads of a particular city into a graph, and I could use them in Netwerkx python but I didn't get any example.
could you help me where to start ? 
first i need an api for city then use it ?

thanks

Comment: Hi Mdeveloper, NetworkX probably isn't the best tool for mapping physical roads, when it maps, it's going to try to map the network connections as best it can where roads, by contrast, are in a fixed location. Check out Shapely or my favorite GeoPandas for mapping information.

Comment: ok .. this is my lead ..  lets go with GeoPandas . thanks . :)

Comment: Without seeing any of your data or what you are trying to do, it's difficult to help check out [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help. Or you can go straight to the source of [Geopandas Documentation](https://geopandas.org/).